# Matlab Matlab installation stuck on WIndows 10 Enterprise (64 bit)

Tags: java, matlab

I have installed Windows 10 Enterprise (64 bit). I have also successfully installed the Java Runtime Environment (v9.Build.83.x64).

The problem is, I cannot install any version of Matlab on the PC. I have tried to install different versions. Each one of the installations became stuck when I clicked on setup of Matlab. The installation does not run Java programs and only its icon in the taskbar is shown, but would not run. This also causes the PC to freeze and makes me run task manager and end task setup of Matlab. I did an install and uninstall java but that does not help either.

Comment: Sounds like there is a problem with Windows 10. Java shouldn't be able to cause the PC to freeze no matter what it does.

Comment: Please help me, I did not install it.

Comment: How to install matlab with problem

Comment: @ASky if you are having trouble installing MATLAB, you should probably call your distributor. That's the one advantage of paying for proprietary software, the people who sold it to you will help you with this sort of thing.

Comment: You need to ensure Windows 10 is installed and working correctly, without this, nothing else will work.